# how to find a regular expression of specific string

Tags: bash, awk

I have a question related to a regular expression. I have a huge text file like

I want to get an output like this

```
 ID           DE
1.1      Transformer
1.12     Best bye
1.1.1    Iphone
```

so basically I want to get ID and DE

what I tried was using awk and sed but with no success. I thought I get the ID and then I get the DE and then I merge them but I still could not figure out how to do that

sed -n ID my.txt

I used **-n** because By default, each line of input is echoed to the standard output after all of the commands have been applied to it.

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't remove samples as it has now become un-clear(when I posted answer sample was there just fyi for all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As OP mentioned in case any `de` is empty with respective `id` then print an hyphen, then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
  print "ID\t\tDE"
}
/ID/{
  if(id){
    print id,de?de:"-"
    id=de=""
  }
  id=$2
  next
}
/DE/{
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  de=$0
}
END{
  if(id){
    print id,de?de:"-"
  }
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
  print "ID\t\tDE"
}
/ID/{
  if(id){
    print id,de
    id=de=""
  }
  id=$2
  next
}
/DE/{
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  de=$0
}
END{
  if(id){
    print id,de
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: Could you simply it? It works but if there is not any DE, for that specific ID, then it gust does not seems to ignore it

Comment: @Learner, can't open file means that it is not able to find it, can you check if file is present in directory where you are trying to run this command?

Comment: @Learner, its simple whichever file you want to run and get output pass its name to this.

Comment: I accepted it already although I do not understand it much ;-) just wondering if it is possible to give an empty or - sign to those ID that do not have DE ?

Comment: @Learner, you mean you don't want to print any`id` which don't have `ie`?

Comment: yes I want to print the ID but instead when there is not any ID, simply mention a dash or hyphen

Comment: @Learner, check EDIT now?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty sed version

```
sed '1 i\
ID DE
   # catch ID info in buffer
   /^[[:blank:]]*ID[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/{
      s///
      h
      d
      }
    # catch DE info in buffer
    /^[[:blank:]]*DE[:blank:]]\{1,\}/{
      s///
      H
      # reformat both info from buffer and print
      x
      s/\n/\t/p
      }
    # avoid any other print
    d
    ' YourFile
```

as oneliner for content

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*ID[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/{s///;h;d;};/^[[:blank:]]*DE[:blank:]]\{1,\}/{s///;H;x;s/\n/\t/p;};d' YourFile
```