# how can I import data which does not load them in few columns

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
ID  DM
1.1.1.22  UDP-glucose 6-dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.23  Histidinol dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.24  Quinate dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.25  Shikimate dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.26  Glyoxylate reductase.
1.1.1.27  L-lactate dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.28  D-lactate dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.29  Glycerate dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.30  3-hydroxybutyrate dehydrogenase.
1.1.1.31  3-hydroxyisobutyrate dehydrogenase.
```

I am trying to load them like the following but it loads them with 3 columns or more. how can I fix this?

```
df <- read.table("path to my data.txt", header=F, fill=T)
```

with this one , I get only one column

```
df <- read.delim2("path to my data.txt", header=F, fill=T)
```

or read.delim

Basically I want it to be only two columns ID and DM

Comment: May be you need to make their field separator as TAB in your input sample file and while reading it in R tell `read.table` function that delimiter is TAB and it should fix it then. My solution(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192789/how-to-find-a-regular-expression-of-specific-string) by which you are getting output should give you in TAB delimited one.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that OP's Input_file is TAB delimited if yes then try following.

```
var <- read.table(Input_file, sep = "\t" , fill=T, header = F, na.strings ="", stringsAsFactors= F)
```

This is just an example, you could edit options as per your need too.

Comment: does not give me the two columns, gives me one

Comment: @Learner, that's because your output may NOT be TAB delimited, in my awk solution it should give you TAB delimited output and then this R one should pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the delimiter to "  " (double space, not sure if that is possible) or put each record in the second column in double quotes.

Comment: OP's sample looks to be TAB delimited so making a delimiter as TAB could help see this once too https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193436/5866580